# How to make an effect plot for GLM model with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, glm

I have a generalized linear model (family - gamma) with interaction, and need to plot it specifically in ggplot2 (on a response scale).
The model was constructed with following code:

```
fit1mult = glm(SIZE_OOCYTE ~ TREATMENT * CASTE, 
               family = Gamma(link = "log"), data=data1)
```

I made a plot using the `lattice` package, and it looks like this:

[image: effect plot]
How can I make a similar one in `ggplot`? I know that the `geom_smooth` has an option `glm`, but don't know how to apply it.

Thanks in advance for suggestions!

**UPD. Solution:**

```
library(ggeffects)

 mydf1 <- ggpredict(fit1mult, terms = c("CASTE", "TREATMENT"))

 plot(mydf1)
```

Result:
[new plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANpm6.png)

Comment: Check ggeffects package

Comment: If you've solved your own problem (even with help!) you're encouraged to post the solution/answer yourself.

Comment: Did it! How can I close the question?